# ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2) in python while I try to run a function

Tags: python, function, machine-learning, data-science

I'm trying to make a seq2seq model following the Tensorflow documentation, which you can find here: https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/tutorials/networks_seq2seq_nmt. However, while I'm trying to run the following lines of code:

```py
class NMTDataset:
  def __init__(self, problem_type='en-ita'):
    self.problem_type = 'en-ita'
    self.inp_lang_tokenizer = None
    self.targ_lang_tokenizer = None
  
  def unicode_to_ascii(self, s):
    return "".join(c for c in unicodedata.normalize('NFD', s) if unicodedata.category(c) != 'Mn')
  
  def preprocess_sentence(self, w):
    w = self.unicode_to_ascii(w.lower().strip())

    w = re.sub(r"([?.!, ¿])", r"\1", w)
    w = re.sub(r"[^a-zA-Z?.!,¿]+", " ", w)

    w = w.strip()

    w = '<start>' + w + '<end>'
    return w

  def create_dataset(self, path, num_examples):
    lines = io.open(path, encoding='UTF-8').read().strip().split('\n')
    word_pairs = [[self.preprocess_sentence(w) for w in l.split('\t')] for l in lines[:num_examples]]

    return zip(*word_pairs)
    
  def tokenize(self, lang):
    lang_tokenizer = tf.keras.preprocessing.text.Tokenizer(filter='', oov_token='<OOV>')
    lang_tokenizer.fit_on_texts(lang)

    tensor = lang_tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(lang)

    tensor = tf.keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(tensor, padding='post')

    return tensor, lang_tokenizer

  def load_dataset(self, path, num_examples=None):
    targ_lang, inp_lang = self.create_dataset(path, num_examples)

    target_tensor, targ_lang_tokenizer = self.tokenize(targ_lang)
    input_tensor, inp_lang_tokenizer = self.tokenize(inp_lang)

    return input_tensor, target_tensor, self.targ_lang_tokenizer, self.inp_lang_tokenizer

  def call(self, num_examples, BATCH_SIZE, BUFFER_SIZE):
    file_path = download_NMT()
    input_tensor, target_tensor, self.inp_lang_tokenizer, self.targ_lang_tokenizer = self.load_dataset(file_path, num_examples)

    input_tensor_train, input_tensor_val, target_tensor_train, target_tensor_val = train_test_split(input_tensor, target_tensor, test_size=0.2)

    train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((input_tensor_train, target_tensor_train))
    train_dataset = train_dataset.shuffle(BUFFER_SIZE).batch(BATCH_SIZE, drop_remainder=True)

    val_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((input_tensor_val, target_tensor_val))
    val_dataset = val_dataset.batch(BATCH_SIZE, drop_remainder=True)

    return train_dataset, val_dataset, self.inp_lang_tokenizer, self.targ_lang_tokenizer  

BUFFER_SIZE = 32000
BATCH_SIZE = 64
num_examples = 30000

dataset_creator = NMTDataset('en-ita')
train_dataset, val_dataset, inp_lang, targ_lang = dataset_creator.call(num_examples, BATCH_SIZE, BUFFER_SIZE)
```

the create_dataset function, and especially the `lines` variable returns me the following ValueError:

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

why is that? can you help me fix it?

Comment: Which line is causing the error?

Comment: where is the code for `preprocess_sentence`?

Comment: Please include the full traceback, not just the error message.